# How to change RadDockableObject position (index) on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to change RadDockableObject position (index) on page load?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to use a RadDock object yet so I can't give you a solid code example, however after scanning the following links for a few minutes, I recommend you give them a visit:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/loadsavelayout/defaultcs.aspx
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dock_dockcontrolcreation.html

Visit some of the links on the left at that second URL because you might find some of those useful as well.